# how to format html table

Tags: html, sql, html-table

im trying to select data from the database and populate a html table with the data, one of the columns is of type Varchar(max) so the string is large and the readability is bad.

the current result is below:

[image: wrong outcome]

the desired outcome is below:
[image: desired outcome]

the only column that needs formatted is the description column.

ive tried several different things including, inserting data into the database with Char(13) etc. as seen below:

> Thrusters (95#)'+ CHAR(13)+ char(10)+ 'Pull-ups'

ive also tried adding style to the  tags like so:

```
  html.Append("<th style width: 40px>");
  html.Append(column.ColumnName);
  html.Append("</th>");
```

this just gave duplicates of the columns. im not sure how this should be done.

below is the code used:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populating a DataTable from database.
            DataTable dt = this.GetData();

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table  border = '1'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {

                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");

                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {

                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.

            FindControl("PlaceHolder1").Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **border-collapse**: table borders are collapsed into a single border

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td:nth-child(2){ text-align:center; }

table td{ padding:5px; }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Length</th>
 <th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fran</td>
  <td>21-15-9 Reps</td>
  <td>Thruster (95#)<br>Pull-ups</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Garrett</td>
  <td>3 Rounds</td>
  <td>75 Squats<br>25 Ring Handstand Push-ups<br>25 L Pull-ups</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the question is more related to how to wrap the text for the description column, and not related to the border styling

Comment: Ok i will see what i can do.